# Динамический график

Tags: excel

Требуеться создать формулу для гафика, которая указывала бы диапазон с 5 последних ячеек в динамической таблице.

Вышло у меня что то вроде этого:

```
=OFFSET($N$13;COUNTA(OFFSET('Calibration Check'!$N$13;;;COUNTA('Calibration Check'!$N$13:$N$40)-1))-5;0;5)
```

При этом удаеться мне только выбрать 5 с конца ячейку в динамической таблице.

Comment: В чем вопрос? Формула не устраивает? Чем именно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> удаеться мне только выбрать 5 с конца ячейку

Нет, формула формирует диапазон. Только в Вашей формуле диапазон 5-ти строк нужно сместить на одну строку ниже. Например, проверьте на сумме:

```
=СУММ(СМЕЩ($N$13;СЧЁТЗ(СМЕЩ($N$13;;;СЧЁТЗ($N$13:$N$40)-1))-4;0;5))
```

Как еще можно проверить? Выделить формулу в строке формул, нажать *F9*. Выделенная часть отобразится в виде результата. Для функции *СМЕЩ* это будет массив значений.

*COUNT(СЧЕТ)* считает и текстовые значения в том числе. А так как график строится по числовым значениям, правильнее применять *COUNT(СЧЕТ)*

```
=СМЕЩ(N13;СЧЁТ(N13:N45)-5;;5)
```

Для диапазона с пустыми ячейками:

```
=СМЕЩ(ИНДЕКС($N:$N;ПРОСМОТР(9E+307;$N$13:$N$40;СТРОКА($N$13:$N$40)));-4;;5)
```

Если формула не в именованном диапазоне, а на листе, лучше убрать летучесть:

```
=ИНДЕКС($N:$N;СЧЁТ($N$13:$N$45)+8):ИНДЕКС($N:$N;СЧЁТ($N$13:$N$45)+12)
```

Без летучести для диапазона с пустыми ячейками:

```
=ИНДЕКС(N:N;ПРОСМОТР(9E+307;N13:N40;СТРОКА(N13:N40))-4):ИНДЕКС(N:N;ПРОСМОТР(9E+307;N13:N40;СТРОКА(N13:N40)+12))
```

Если нужно,  к диапазонам добавить имя листа